# How can I prevent deploying code to the wrong function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have developed a number of JavaScript functions that all get deployed to an Azure Function App. I have two different code sets intended for two different Azure FAs. Unfortunately, when the FAs were created they were not given a meaningful name, and instead are just a random string of letters and numbers.

I primarily deploy my code to Azure from within VSCode, and that seems to work fine. However, I have a strong concern that one day I will deploy one set of functions to the wrong FA, which would of course cause big problems.

Is there anywhere that I can define a list of "allowed" function apps, so that if I were to attempt deploying the code to another FA it would fail? Or is there another method to achieve a similar result?

As of right now, I can deploy any codebase to any FA.

Answer (score 0):

> To prevent deploying code to the wrong function:

There are few methods for restricting deployment to only particular    `Function Apps` and preventing deployment to undesired `Function Apps`.

***Use Deployment slots:***

As detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#add-a-slot), You can choose a deployment slot for a function app which has a different `URL` than function app.

- Instead of executing immediately in a production environment, you can test any fixes or incorrect deployments in a different deployment slot before it goes live by deploying it into a secondary deployment slot.
- Because it is your `production environment slot`, your users will be accessing your original `Function App`.

***How to work with Deployment Slots:***

Goto `Function App` and you will find `Deployment slots` under `deployment` and then `Add a slot` as described in the below image:

[image]

*You can also create a deployment slot using* `Az CLI` command [az functionapp deployment slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment/slot?view=azure-cli-latest).

*Use below format:*

```bash
az functionapp deployment slot create --name <Functionapp> --resource-group <ResourceGroup> --slot "slot1"
```

***Use Deployment Scripts:***

When you deploy your code, you can specify a deployment script, which can be a `CLI or PowerShell` script.

- You can create a deployment script that verifies the target `Function App's` name and fails if it does not match one of the given `Function Apps`.

Goto `Azure Portal` and search for `Deployment Scripts` to work with this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @jahnavi for your response. Neither of these are quite what I was hoping for but it sounds like that simply doesn't exist at this time. I had heard of, though not used yet, the deployment slots. However, the deployment script I am unfamiliar with. I will have to review both of these to see which would work best for us, much appreciated!